# J-link connection error when connecting from Kinetis Design Studio IDE

Tags: debugging, segger-jlink

I am using  KDS for debugging a MQX RTOS tower kit. When I tried debugging the project the error on the image occurs.

http://gyazo.com/87346d5c944b406341bf8535bc93e55f

I checked device manager and my computer sees the device in USB port. How can I solve this problem or where can I find any information about it. Thank you.

And following image shows my debug configurations

http://gyazo.com/a0a8886688055602dbd659cb5e697601

Comment: Does the stand alone J-Link app work?

Comment: No I tried to run JlinkGDBServer.exe but it gives the same result

Comment: Does it not say anything in a log? IIRC, a log file is created in your drive root

Comment: When is log file created? after I run J-link.exe or  after project debugging? (Sorry  I am new in these topics)

Comment: It used to create it every time, but it might need a command argument and it might be saved somewhere else. It should also show if something is wrong.

Comment: Excuse me but what should I search for? I mean what is the name of log file ? @leppie

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue with KDS 3.2.0 and J-Link V5.12i. I did all my troubleshooting with J-link.exe (Commander). The problem was that the FRDM-KW41Z development board I had didn't have the J-link OpenSDA firmware installed from Segger. I found my dev board in [this list](https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink) under section titled "J-Link OpenSDA - Board-Specific Firmwares" and downloaded the bin file. The [followed instructions here](https://www.segger.com/opensda.html) to properly flash it on my board. This is what the flashing was like:

[image]

[image]

Once I updated the board with J-Link OpenSDA, then I checked with J-Link.exe and the issue highlighted here was resolved:

[image]